# Is it possible to change color of blocks in pyxdsm？

Tags: python

I use `pyxdsm` package to generate XDSM diagram, in which different types of blocks have different colors, such as "OPT" is blue, "FUNC" is green, "SLOVER" is orange. Is it possible to change color of certain block? I cannot find useful information online. This is the documentation of pyxdsm package https://mdolab-pyxdsm.readthedocs-hosted.com/.

Sorry to ask this simple question, I appreciate for any help!